# Is there some neural network that implements Least Squares?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, supervised-learning, model-request

I would like to build supervised NN that gets a matrix $A$ and vector $b$ as inputs and returns $x$ as a close result of the Least Squares algorithm for $Ax=b$.

I looked for so works in the field and the only one that I found is [this one](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18267865/). The paper is from 1994 and it's about analog NN. Maybe you have seen a work on the subject?